# Adding Dublin Core content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, seo, dublin-core

I am adding Dublin Core content to a web page using JavaScript (jQuery).

The problem is that when I view the source of the page (View→Source) it does not show the recently added content, however when I press F12 on IE, view the HTML then I see the content.

Is this ok? Will the search engines be able to pick this up or am I doing something wrong? If it's wrong, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behavior, any html inserted using JavaScript code will not be visible in the view source but will show up in the developer tool. Whether this DOM will be visible to search engine depends on the Search Engine. Google has recently started to [crawl and index](http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/05/google-renders-css-js-hints) some web pages with JS content. However, this is still a new technology and may not be perfect. It is better to use [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home) to view and analyze your sites for SEO data.

Comment: But how do people do this then in reality, I have a CMS system and the Dublin core stuff have to be dynamically generated based on some properties of the page.